# AWK - Add variable and result of function to variable

Tags: awk

I want to add variable and result of function in AWK. Input:

```
t t t t
a t a ta
ata ta a a
```

Script:

```
{
key="t"
print gsub(key,"")#<-it's work
b=b+gsub(key,"")#<- it's something wrong
}
END{
print b}#<-so this is 0
```

Output:

```
4
2
2
0#<-the last print
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code, as [Brandon Xavier pointed out](https://superuser.com/a/965236/150988),
is that `gsub` doesn’t just *count* matches; it actually replaces them. 
So, for instance,

```
{
    print
    print gsub("t", "")
    print
    print gsub("t", "")
    print
    print "----------"
}
```

would print

```
t t t t
4

0

----------
a t a ta
2
a  a a
0
a  a a
----------
ata ta a a
2
aa a a a
0
aa a a a
----------
```

If you don’t care about corrupting your input data
(i.e., if counting the `t`s is the *only* thing you want to do with them),
you can use Brandon’s suggestion:

```
{
    x = gsub("t", "")
    print x
    b=b+x
}
END {print b}
```

The above is, arguably, the best answer,
inasmuch as it eliminates your redundant `gsub` calls. 
(The following approaches still use two calls to `gsub`.)

If you want to avoid adding a new variable,
you can do so by making the substitution non-destructive:

```
{
    key="t"
    print gsub(key, key)
    b=b+gsub(key, key)
}
END {print b}
```

i.e., replace the `t`s with themselves,
so they’re still there when you do the second `gsub`. 
(You could also use `gsub(key, "&")` to replace `key` with itself.)

Another approach is to make the first `gsub`
modify something other than the actual input line:

```
{
    temp=$0
    print gsub("t", "", temp)
    b = b + gsub("t", "")
}
END {print b}
```

Comment: Replace the 't's with themselves - so easy. I can't explain why I didn't think about this solution.I have to back to notes and bash. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

gsub doesn't just count the occurences, it actually replaces them.  The first print statement you have in there (presumably for debugging) is breaking it.

Comment: So, there is some function, which only count matching text?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I'd just do something like '{ key = "t"; x = gsub(key,""); print x; b=b+x; }

Comment: @BrandonXavier, you should put the correct code in your answer.